# Django - Filter view by category from two models

Tags: python, django, filter, view

I extended my post models and now my `post_list_by_category` function shows ugly lists.It shows 2 or more different categories where only posts from one category should be displayed.
This app uses 2 types of post models, so somehow I need to get them together but filtered by the categories they belong too. Any idea?

Old working with one Model:

```
def post_list_by_category(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=pk)
    list_posts = Post.objects.get_queryset().order_by('-pk') 
    paginator = Paginator(list_posts, 10)  # Show 10 Posts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'MyProject/post_list_by_category.html', {'posts': posts, 'category': category})
```

New not working with two models:

```
def post_list_by_category(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=pk)
    list_posts = list(chain(Post.objects.get_queryset().order_by('-pk'), Post_Extra.objects.get_queryset().order_by('-pk')))
    paginator = Paginator(list_posts, 10)  # Show 10 Posts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'MyProject/post_list_by_category.html', {'posts': posts, 'category': category})
```

models.py

Post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Post Title", max_length=25)
content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Post Content", max_length=5000)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

....

Post_Extra:

```
class PostExtra(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Post Title", max_length=25)
content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Post Content", max_length=10000)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

....
other fields are not necessary but they have differences

Category
...

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Title")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=175, null=True, blank=True)
```

...
Kind regards

Comment: You are not filtering your `Post` queryset in any way. Also we don't know how they are related to each other or what fields your `Post` and `Post_Extra` models have. It doesn't appear that even your first example is somehow filtered by category.

Answer (score 0):

That solved the issue:

```
def post_list_by_category(request, pk):
    category = Category.objects.get(pk=pk)
    list_posts = list(chain(Post.objects.filter(category_id=pk).order_by('-pk'), PostExtra.objects.filter(category_id=pk).order_by('-pk')))
    paginator = Paginator(list_posts, 10)  # Show 10 Posts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    posts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'MyProject/post_list_by_category.html', {'posts': posts, 'category': category})
```